# unexpected output for printing a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector

I don't understand the output of my program. I'm simply trying to loop through a vector of objects and print their member functions. The code is something like this:

.cpp file :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/* 
 * File:   Odometer.cpp
 * Author: Adrian
 * 
 * Created on May 18, 2017, 6:29 PM
 */

#include "Odometer.h"

Odometer::Odometer() {
    miles = 0;
    efficiency = 0;
}

void::Odometer::resetOdometer() {
    miles = 0;
}

void::Odometer::setEfficiency(double efficiency) {
    this->efficiency = efficiency;
}
void::Odometer::setMiles(int miles) {
    this->miles = miles;
}


void::Odometer::addToOdometer(int milesDriven ){
    miles=miles+ milesDriven;
}
//to self:really unsure what this is 

double::Odometer::gasolineConsumed(){
   return miles/efficiency;
}

double::Odometer::getEfficiency(){
   return efficiency;
}

int::Odometer::getMiles(){
   return miles;
}    

Odometer::Odometer(const Odometer& orig) {
}    

//to self:really unsure what this is

Odometer::~Odometer() {
}
```

and the main file:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: Adrian
 *
 * Created on May 18, 2017, 6:28 PM
 */

#include "Odometer.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;    


template <typename T>
std::string NumberToString(T Number) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << Number;
    return ss.str();
}

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int miles;
    double efficiency;
    int numberTrips;
    vector<Odometer> v;
    cout << "Please enter the amount of trips taken : " << endl;
    cin >> numberTrips;
    cout << NumberToString(1) << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberTrips; i++) {
        cout << "Please enter number of miles for trip "  << NumberToString(i) << endl;
        cin >> miles;
        cout << "Please enter the efficiency for trip "  << NumberToString(i) << endl;
        cin >> efficiency;
        Odometer obj;
        obj.setMiles(miles);
        cout << "miles "  << obj.getMiles() ;

        obj.setEfficiency(efficiency);
        cout << "efficiency "  << obj.getEfficiency();
        v.push_back(obj);    
    }

    //the bug         

    for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 1; i != v.size()+1; i++) {

        cout << "Miles driven for trip " << NumberToString(i) << " is "  << v[i].getMiles() << endl;
         cout << "Efficiency for trip " << NumberToString(i) << " is "  << v[i].getEfficiency() << endl;
         cout << "Gasoline consumed for trip " <<  NumberToString(i) << " is "  << v[i].gasolineConsumed() << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I should enter the number of miles than the efficiency in miles per gallon and then the gasoline consumed . The output should be the number of miles efficiency and gasoline consumed.

my console output:

```
Please enter the amount of trips taken : 
1
1
Please enter number of miles for trip 1
10
Please enter the efficiency for trip 1
1
miles 10efficiency 1Miles driven for trip 1 is 16439
Efficiency for trip 1 is 1.51332e-306
Gasoline consumed for trip 1 is 1.#INF
```

Comment: You need to also include what you expect the output to be. Also, I can see this being problem with code you haven't included in the question. Include code that may be relevant, and try to make a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: ok should i repost?

Comment: @user7338821 just edit your current post and make it clear what is the expected output

Comment: You still do not describe how your actual output is different from your expected output. Some sample input would be useful aswell. Your `NumberToString` function is superfluous, cout knows how to display an int, you can just remove it.

Comment: Am I missing something or is this line just bizarre? `for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 1; i != v.size()+1; i++) {` ? (even if we don't want to use an iterator...)

Comment: something is wrong with v[i].getMiles

Comment: You've now included your input and output, but you haven't stated what you think is wrong with the output and what you expected it to be..

Comment: the number of miles should be what i typed in 10 instead of 16349 likewise the effiecieny should be what i typed 1 not 1.51332e-306

Answer (score 0):

Array/vector indexing in C++ starts at index 0, not 1.  You get the results you see because you are accessing outside the bounds of the vector.

Your output loop should be

```
for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
```

Or use iterators instead of indexing.

Comment: i wanted to start at 1 because i wanted to name the trips starting at 1 instead of 0.  the changes still produce crazy values is there anything wrong with v.[i].getGalons?

Comment: Your copy constructor `Odometer::Odometer(const Odometer& orig)` doesn't do anything and it needs to.

Comment: cout << "miles" << v[0].getMiles() ;  prints 6029508 instead  of what i typed in for the value "10"

Comment: Because `push_back` will use the copy constructor, and your copy constructor doesn't copy the values it needs to copy.  So the value stored in the vector will be uninitialized (garbage).

Comment: ok deleting it worked im unsure why though netbeans added that automatically

Comment: why does it use the copy constructor , im quite new to c++

Comment: When you push back it places a copy in the vector, it makes that copy by calling the copy constructor. If you don't define a copy constructor then the compiler defines one that just copies each member of the class. If you define it as empty it does not create the default and calls yours which leaves the members in your copy uninitialised. You only need to define a copy constructor yourself if the default one would do the 'wrong thing'.